# Auto Generate Code/Text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

I'm working on a project that works on ticketing technique, I need to generate an field that generate a code could be inserted into the DB.

And the code have specified form contains 3 or 4 letters, date, and auto-incremented number like:

`PRUC-120717-0001` --> `PRUC-120717-0002`

OR

`PRUC-12/07/17-0001` --> `PRUC-12/07/17-0002`

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? What have you tried so far? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My Question is, is there a way to make a filed to generate the upper form I mentioned in the quotes?

I'm still searching for the way as it's the first time for me to do this type of job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive created a system like this.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$proc = "PRUC";
$date = date('m-d-Y');


 $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as total from mytable where SUBSTRING(produc, 1, 6)='$proc'");
                    $sth->execute();
                    $number_of_rows = $sth->fetchColumn();

                    if($number_of_rows<=0){
                        $number_of_rows;
                    }
                        $total = $number_of_rows + 1;

echo $proc.$date.sprintf('%04d', $total);
?>
```

in the query it wil count the how many pruc and auto increment by 1

Ex. in database we have PRUC-12/07/17-0001 next insert will be PRUC-12/07/17-0002.

Comment: https://uploadfiles.io/ool9o heres a link for the demo

Comment: This one worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

click the link for the codes
[www.uploadfiles.io/ool9o](http://www.uploadfiles.io/ool9o)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function getLoadCode($currentdate) {
        $productid = str_pad($load_id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $productid = "PRUC".$currentdate;
        return $productid;
    }
```